# Show email in Sitecore forms Thank you message

Tags: sitecore-forms

I want to show the email that the user entered in Sitecore forms while submitting the form in thank message.
How to achieve this?

Example:

```
Hi, user: abc:gmail.com
form submitted successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this approach to implement the functionality.

- In the Sitecore Forms designer, select the submit button.
- In the right sidebar, under the "Submit Action" section, add a "Redirect to Page" action.
- Click on the newly added action and configure the "Query string" field.
- Use tokens to pass form field values. For example, if you have a field named "Email," you can use {Email} in the query string.
- Navigate to the thank you page in the Sitecore Content Editor.
- Edit the content of the thank you page to include placeholders for the form field values. For example, you can use tokens like {QueryString.Email} to display the value of the "Email" field.

This is how your Thank You page content looks like

```
<p>Thank you, {QueryString.Name}, for submitting the form!</p>
<p>Your email address: {QueryString.Email}</p>
```

**Using the Custom Submit Action**

If the above doesn't work for you try this code in your custom submit action method.

```
public void Execute(FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
    {
        // Get the path or ID of the thank you page item
        string thankYouPagePath = "/sitecore/content/YourWebsite/ThankYouPage";

        // Use Sitecore API to retrieve the item
        Item thankYouPageItem = Context.Database.GetItem(thankYouPagePath);

        if (thankYouPageItem != null)
        {
            // Get the content from the item
            string thankYouPageContent = thankYouPageItem["YourField"];

            // Add your logic to display or process the thank you page content like getting the field of the page and replace with email.

   // Access form fields and their values
    foreach (IViewModel field in formSubmitContext.Fields)
    {
        // Check if the field is a text field
        if (field is IValueField<string> textField)
        {
            string fieldName = textField.Name;
            string fieldValue = textField.Value;

            // Use fieldName and fieldValue as needed
        }
        // You can add more conditions for other field types (checkboxes, dropdowns, etc.)
    }

            formSubmitContext.RedirectOnSuccess = "/path-to-custom-thank-you-page";
        }

        // Continue with the default form submission behavior
        GetPageRenderingArgs args = new GetPageRenderingArgs(Context.Item, Context.Database);
        Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageRendering.GetPageRendering pipeline = new Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageRendering.GetPageRendering();
        pipeline.Process(args);
    }
```

This [link](https://sitecorediaries.org/2021/09/08/creating-custom-submit-action-to-send-the-emails-in-sitecore-forms/) can work to understand the process of custom submit action.

Hope this will work for you.